# python. function in function

Tags: python, function, return

I'm new to Python and I have problem with this code:

```
def dirs(currentDir):
    exe = True
    allDirs = os.listdir(currentDir)
    print "Directories in %s:" % currentDir
    for files in allDirs:
        print files
    direc = raw_input("Directory name?:")

    if direc == "--q":
        exe = False
    elif currentDir == "/" and exe == True:
        theDir =  currentDir + direc
        dirs(theDir)
    elif currentDir != "/" and exe == True:
        theDir = currentDir + "/" + direc
        dirs(theDir)
    print "should return"
```

Why, when I type *--q*, prints *should return* several times?
If directory is /home/username/, it will print three times, if directory is /home/ it will print two times and so on.
I also tried to return in if statement:

```
if direc == "--q":
    return something
```

But then nothing happens.
Any ideas?
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you fix your indentation in the post? That would be very useful for reading Python, thanks.

Comment: what exactly is this code supposed to do? could you explain that? might help us help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've understood from your comments, this should do the correct thing.

```
def dirs(currentDir):
    allDirs = os.listdir(currentDir)
    print "Directories in %s:" % currentDir
    for files in allDirs:
        print files
    direc = raw_input("Directory name?:")

    if direc != "--q":
        theDir =  os.path.join(currentDir, direc)
        return dirs(theDir)
    else:
        return currentDir
```

**Discussion of the code as provided by you**

Please add more information to your post what the code *should* do. Meanwhile, see here for a semantically equivalent function, it does the *exact same* thing as your function, but I have removed certain unnecessary things.

```
def dirs(currentDir):
    allDirs = os.listdir(currentDir)
    print "Directories in %s:" % currentDir
    for files in allDirs:
        print files
    direc = raw_input("Directory name?:")

    if direc != "--q":
        theDir =  os.path.join(currentDir, direc)
        dirs(theDir)
    print "should return"
```

Now, as long as you don't enter `--q`, it will never print "should return".

What is the `exe` variable for in your program? It doesn't do *anything*.

If the first `if` clause is executed, *non* of the others will be excuted, because `if/elif/.../else` are mutually exclusive clauses. Once you set `exe = True`, `exe` will *never* be accessed again. Thus, you can remove `exe` from your code – as it stands – entirely. Perhaps, though, you wanted it to do something different than preventing those `elif` clauses from executing.

As for `should return`

- You will always see *at least* one `should return`.
- For every time you *don't* enter `--q`, you will see `should return` once more
- They all print after you enter `--q`, because it the print statement is after the recursive call.

Further, I replaced your directory name handling logic with `os.path.join()` which works across all platforms.

Here the current behavior:

```
>>> dirs(r"C:\Python27")
Directories in C:\Python27:
DLLs
Doc
include
Lib
libs
LICENSE.txt
NEWS.txt
python.exe
pythonw.exe
README.txt
Removesetuptools.exe
Scripts
setuptools-wininst.log
tcl
Tools
w9xpopen.exe
Directory name?:Doc
Directories in C:\Python27\Doc:
python273.chm
Directory name?:--q
should return
should return
```

### Recursion

Compare these two functions to see the effect for handling output before and after the recursive call:

```
def string_foo(text):
    first, rest = text[0], text[1:]
    print first
    if rest:
        string_foo(rest)




def string_bar(text):
    first, rest = text[0], text[1:]
    if rest:
        string_foo(rest)
    print first
```

Output:

```
>>> string_foo("Hello")
H
e
l
l
o

>>> string_bar("Hello")
o
l
l
e
H
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the tips! Sorry, I haven't noticed about `print "should return"`, it remained from debugging. Instead of `print "should return"`, should be `return currentDir`. Then You can browse through directories and if You type _--q_ (which means quit), function would return directory in which you are. So If I type _--q_, I want to return directory in which I am.

Comment: @Taadas So you want to go one directory up?

Comment: It's like browsing through directories and when I type _--q_ exit function by returning current directory in which I am.

Comment: In the example, I start in `C:\Python27`, then I enter the `Doc` directory. Then I type `--q`, would you like it to go back to `C:\Python27`?

Comment: @Taadas, forgot to mention you.

Comment: No. If You start in `C:\Python27`, then You enter the `Doc` directory. Then You type `--q` and then function should return `C:\Python27\Doc`.

Comment: @Taadas Have a look at the very top of my post, that should work. As you can see, it took a lot of discussion to finally understand what you meant. For your next posts, think about what was missing now: Describe as best you can what the code should do, add a small example. This helps us tremendously and you will be rewarded with *better* answers much quicker.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I was in hurry. Many thanks for help and tips!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me to be related to the recursiveness of your function. If you enter two directories while using your program, you would expect 3 "should return"s to be printed, since there are three calls to dirs().

Comment: I thought there was problem with functions. But how I need to rewrite code that function would work normally?

Comment: @Taadas: The question is: What do you want your code to do exactly? The code I posted should do the *exact same thing* as yours, and it *does* work. The question is, does it do what you want?